# bash shell - node - arduino - ino : connecting with redirects

Tags: node.js, bash, redirect, arduino

I have an arduino script that reads from a serial port and then prints out the values received to stdout with `Serial.println`.  I also have a nodeJS script that outputs a rate using `console.log()`.  I would like to "connect" the two scripts, so that the output of the node script feeds the input of the arduino script.

To build/upload/run the arduino script I'm using `ino` (http://inotool.org/)

```
$ino build && ino upload
$ino serial
```

To run the node script,

```
$node rate.js
```

and the output is something like,

```
$node rate.js
45
67
12
78
56
```

Inside `rate.js` I have `console.log(rate)` for printing the rates as they arrive.

What I was hoping would work would be something like,

```
$ino serial < node rate.js > arduino_output.txt
```

I''m hoping to do this with redirects.  Unfortunately, I can not use one of the many awesome node modules out there for connecting the arduino to node.

Does anyone know how to do this with shell redirects?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do the following:

```
node rate.js | ino serial > arduino_output.txt
```

This pipes the output of the `node` command as the input of the `ino serial` command. What I do not know is whether `ino serial` accets stdin like this.

If it doesn't, you could look at using `picocom` directly (which is what `ino` uses under the covers.